Help with a PnC proof
I came across a statement:
The number of ways of dividing n distinct objects into l groups containing p objects each & m groups containing q objects each is equal to
$$\frac{n!}{(p!)^l(q!)^ml!m!}$$
Here lp+mq=n
I couldn't manage to prove it, help me

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

If you are familiar with group actions there's a really fun way to prove this (however, it is basically stated in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93629/1387803 without the group action interpretation).
Let $S_n$ be the group of all permutations of the set $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Define $M$ as the set of all possible decompositions of the set $[n]$ into $A_1,\ldots,A_l$ containing $p$ elements and $B_1,\ldots,B_m$ containing $q$ elements. The group $S_n$ acts on $M$ via
$$\sigma\cdot \{A_1,\ldots,A_l,B_1,\ldots,B_m\}:=\{\sigma(A_1),\ldots,\sigma(A_l),\sigma(B_1),\ldots,\sigma(B_m)\},$$ where $\sigma(A):=\{\sigma(a)\mid a\in A\}$. Choose any $\{A_1,\ldots,A_l,B_1,\ldots,B_m\}\in M$, then we can obtain every element out of $M$ by multiplying an appropriate $\sigma\in S_n$ onto $\{A_1,\ldots,A_l,B_1,\ldots,B_m\}$ (this means $S_n$ acts transitively on $M$). Hence, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem we get $$|M|=\frac{|S_n|}{|Stab_{S_n}(\{A_1,\ldots,A_l,B_1,\ldots,B_m\})|}.$$ The only thing left now is to show that the stabilizer has the size $(p!)^l(q!)^ml!m!$.
So we want to determine the number of elements $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $$\{\sigma(A_1),\ldots,\sigma(A_l),\sigma(B_1),\ldots,\sigma(B_m)\}=\{A_1,\ldots,A_l,B_1,\ldots,B_m\}.$$ Every such $\sigma$ permutes the $A_i$'s and $B_k$'s seperately. Let's look at what $\sigma$ can do with the $A_i$'s (because we will see that for the $B_k$'s it's the same).
There are two things $\sigma$ does:

It permutes the blocks $A_1,\ldots,A_l$ $\to$ this gives the $l!$
It permutes the elements in each block $A_i$ $\to$ in every block we have $p!$ possible ways to permute, hence $(p!)^l$

Similarly, it permutes the $B_k$'s and the elements in the $B_k$'s. Since what $\sigma$ does to the $A_i$'s is independent from what it does with the $B_k$'s, we get the desired number of elements in the stabilizer.
